# Controlling cookies with many tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies

I have a peculiar problem. My application has differents levels of autentication and, one specific level (sup user) need to be able to use the application as another user (sub user), who has lower privileges.

We established that when sup user select the sub user, another tab in the browser will be opened, and will load the sub user privileges and his respective cookie.
The problem we have is: how could we get the reference for the new cookie in this new tab?

Also the sup user will be able to open so many tabs, and each tab need to reference his own cookie.

Comment: There is another way to do this control or something similar?

Comment: I think your sup user should be set up to be allowed to view data of sub user without looking at the cookies. Meaning, when you are logged in as sup, the sup authentication cookie works for any sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sup user should be set up to be allowed to view data of sub user without looking at the cookies. Meaning, when you are logged in as sup, the sup authentication cookie works for any sub. Does this make any sense to you?

When you are trying to retrieve data for sub, either ask for credentials/cookie of the sub or check if there is a cookie for the sup. If there is a cookie for the sup or the user provides the credentials for the sup, you are good to go.

Comment: In this context, how could I know which sub user is making changes in the system? How I can control this?

Comment: You will know because you will have the ID of the account that is being changed.

Comment: Understood, but my problem now is how to persist this ID trough the pages that the super user can access, remembering that him can open many tabs. Any idea?

Comment: Urls are probably your best bet. Then you can have different one in each window. Other than that, you can make postbacks to the server with the ID of the account, and carry data over that way.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll follow this.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no way to directly limit the scope of a cookie in such a manner. However, one solution to your problem would be to create a mirror URL to your website and limit the path of the cookies to the mirrors; for example, limit the path of normal cookies to `www.example.com`, but create a mirror URL `mirror.example.com` (that uses a symlink or other feature to point to `www.example.com` internally). However, that is not only quite a lot of work for what you'd like to do, but is limited to only allowing the main user and one alternate user.

Another solution, not cookie-dependent, would be to create a GET variable that, when appended to a URL on your website, would cause a sufficiently privledged user to impersonate another one (e.g. `&altUser=subUser`). Then, to make this persistent within a tab, automatically append that same variable to the end of every link on a page generated with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried the second solution as you said, but it's very hard to persist the url parameter through entire application.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard. Your routes should require the ID of the account somehow like this: /Account/Edit/89 and then each link that is on the page should also have the ID, /Account/AddAddress/89 or /Account/RemoveCreditCard/89